# Vertically align absolute positioned DIV with left value inside TD element in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have positioned some div element inside the TD element with left value by using **position: absolute and left** value but i need to align the div vertically in middle without fixed margin and padding value, because my TD height can be anything . I have added sample for reference, any help?

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Works in chrome, Firefox, Edge but not in IE 11*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:300px;height:30px;'>
      <div class='content'>
      </div>
      <div class='content2'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline-block` for the div's and `vertical-align:middle` for the cell. It then aligns the div's vertical in the middle, no matter how high the table row is.

```
  .content {
     display: inline-block;
     background: grey;
     width: 100px;
     height: 20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
  tr{
    height: 90px;
  }
   td {
     border: 1px solid grey;
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }

   .div1{
     margin-left: 20px;
   }
   .div2{
     margin-left: 40px;
   }

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:300px;height:30px;'>
      <div class='content div1'>
      </div>
      <div class='content div2'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9dhxa3c/1/)

**Note** that, unlike `float`, with `inline-block` *whitespace* between the div's will be displayed! So unless you code them as `<div>...</div><div>...</div>` you can see some unwanted extra space.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, but in my case, i want place div in particular position(left) from table, so i must set position as absolute.

Comment: Why? Just add a margin-left.

Comment: On a sidenote: the `height` property on a table cell won't work, it works on the table row or the content.

Comment: Thanks for the help, we can place, but in my application these div can fall at same position, these are placed with some calculations from starting point of table.